# How do I edit loop names for the Apple loop library?

Tags: music, garageband

I want to use more memorable names for loops that I have added to my Apple loop library, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the loop name is derived from the filename, so change the filename of the loop and the loop name displayed within the Apple loop library.